# Why doesn't work draggable in https://jsfiddle.net/Lbs785ez/2/?

Tags: jquery, draggable

Have some trouble with dragging div.
My html template:

```
</html> 
<div id="photo_page">  
    <div id="photo_page_frame" style="margin:0; width: 80%; height: 80%; background: url({PHOTO_IMG_SRC}) 50% 50% no-repeat; background-size: contain;"></div> 
</div>
```

Then, I want to to drag div `photo_page_frame` using the mouse:

```
$(function(){
    // fill PHOTO_IMG_SRC and fade in #photo_page
    $('#photo_page_frame').draggable();
});
```

```css
#photo_page {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=80);
    z-index: 99999;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    display: none;
    pointer-events: none;
    align: center;
}
```

But div `#photo_page` is not draggable, but the `draggable="true"` attribute exists at runtime. Help me, please

Comment: Please fix the drah - > drag typo in your heading. Please take time to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. "Spelling, grammar and punctuation are important! Remember, this is the first part of your question others will see - you want to make a good impression."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make two DIVs draggable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272269/how-to-make-two-divs-draggable)

Comment: Okay, why https://jsfiddle.net/Lbs785ez/1/ doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

The 'draggable' seems to be a function of jQuery UI, so you need to load the correct script.